# Change background-color of div for some time and then go back to previous

Tags: jquery, html, background-color

I have a page with many divs. I would need to change the backcolor of a defined set of divs for a given time. The set is defined by the class it has, for example

```
<div id="A00010002-1" class="playerbox winner ITTTI00582" style="background-color: ......>
```

The class in this case is `ITTTI00582`. there will be a few other divs on the page that share this same class. This Class is generated on Runtime, thus it is not backed in the CSS file.

I would need to color all the divs with this class within a function, and then revert the color to whatever it was before. This did not work:

```
$('.' + idclass).css('background-color', '#FFFF00');
```

Also, once I assign the color, how can I delete the assignment?

Comment: add or remove class with style

Comment: Use a class instead of css .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` to execute some code after a given delay. Try this:

```
var $elements = $('.' + idclass).addClass('highlight');
setTimeout(function() {
    $elements.removeClass('highlight')
}, 5000); // 5000ms = 5 seconds
```

Note the use of `addClass()` and `removeClass()` here. It's better practice as it separates the styling logic from the JS code, and makes it easier to reset the element to its original state when the class is removed.

Here's a working example:

```js
var idclass = 'ITTTI00582';

var $elements = $('.' + idclass).addClass('highlight');
setTimeout(function() {
  $elements.removeClass('highlight')
}, 5000); // 5000ms = 5 seconds
```

```css
.playerbox.winner { background-color: grey; }
.playerbox.winner.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A00010002-1" class="playerbox winner ITTTI00581">ITTTI00581</div>
<div id="A00010002-1" class="playerbox winner ITTTI00582">ITTTI00582</div>
<div id="A00010002-1" class="playerbox winner ITTTI00583">ITTTI00583</div>
<div id="A00010002-1" class="playerbox winner ITTTI00584">ITTTI00584</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but would i need to define a class "highlite" within the css? do i get it correctly: I use the ITTTI00582 only to define which divs get the additional class highlight added?

Comment: That's right, you'd need to add that class. I added a working example for you

Comment: it does not seem to be working on my end.. The class is not assigned. (i temporarely removed the timeout) and if i rightclick-> examine object I see it has all classes except the one mentioned. I also verified with a message box that the idclass variable is correct and it is.

Comment: It sounds like the class you've created is not specific enough to override the existing `background-color`. Note in my example above I used `.playerbox.winner.highlight` to ensure the class was ranked over the existing one

Comment: the winner class is not specific for all divs.. so i created it like this: div.playerbox.highlight but it still istn't working. I also removed the background, and the only color definition that remains is .playerbox and .winner that applies to this specific div. stil, it takes the color from the .winner class

Comment: i added this after the addclass (the ID is of one of the divs with the same class) and it returned all classes BUT the highlite: alert ($('#C00020002-2').attr('class'));

Comment: never mind, found the problem.. a Ajax call was resetting the classes.. Thank you!